# how to split the path it a particular node is greater than 10 characters remove underscore and make first letter caps?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here I'm getting the output but if a string is greater than 15 characters it should be split.

```
const a = "/qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg /sub node 01"
   
expected output = "Qar reg qar reg.../Sub node 01"

const a = "/_dept/jtyut"

expected output = "Dept/Jtyut"

const path = e.toLowerCase().replace('_', '');
    return path.replace(/(?:^|[\s-/])\w/g, function (match) {
      return match.toUpperCase();
    })
```

Comment: Please add proper quotes to your inputs. That looks like a regex literal

Comment: So, nodes are separated with `/` and hyphen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most efficient solution, but this method is effective and easy to read:

```js
function CleanPath(p){
    return p.split("/")   //  Split on /
        .filter(i => i.length > 0)   //  Remove empty elements
        .map(i => i.replace(/^_/, ''))   //  Remove leading underscores
        .map(i => i.length > 15 ? i.substr(0, 15) + "..." : i)   //  Limit to 15 characters + ...
        .map(i => i.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + i.slice(1))   // Uppercase leading character
        .join("/");   // Join on /
}

console.log(CleanPath("/qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg /sub node 01"));
console.log(CleanPath("/_dept/jtyut"));
```

---

If you prefer you can merge all the `map` calls into one:

```js
function CleanPath(p){
    return p.split("/")   //  Split on /
        .filter(i => i.length > 0)   //  Remove empty elements
        .map(i => {
            i = i.replace(/^_/, '');   //  Remove leading underscores
            i = i.length > 15 ? i.substr(0, 15) + "..." : i;   //  Limit to 15 characters + ...
            return i.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + i.slice(1);   // Uppercase leading character
        })
        .join("/");   // Join on /
}

console.log(CleanPath("/qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg /sub node 01"));
console.log(CleanPath("/_dept/jtyut"));
```

---

And if you need IE support you can replace the arrow functions with regular function bodies:

```js
function CleanPath(p){
    return p.split("/")   //  Split on /
        .filter(function(i){ return i.length > 0; })   //  Remove empty elements
        .map(function(i){
            i = i.replace(/^_/, '');   //  Remove leading underscores
            i = i.length > 15 ? i.substr(0, 15) + "..." : i;   //  Limit to 15 characters + ...
            return i.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + i.slice(1);   // Uppercase leading character
        })
        .join("/");   // Join on /
}

console.log(CleanPath("/qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg qar reg /sub node 01"));
console.log(CleanPath("/_dept/jtyut"));
```

Comment: Why are you using a separate `map` for each logic instead of clubbing them together something like `map( i => { i = i.replace(..); if(i.length > 15) i = i.substr(...); return i.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + i.slice(1) })`

Comment: @adiga I prefer it in terms of readability, like I said, not the most _efficient_, but I find it easier to read, even if using line breaks inside the lambda body. I do understand your point though

Comment: @adiga Edited to include a couple more options